# How use this "Tree Age Calculator" to WordPress function and Callback to WP Post

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, calculator

Here is the JavaScript code that I tried use to calculate the age of a tree based on the diameter and species of the tree:

```
function calculateAge() {
   // get the diameter and species of the tree from the form
   var diameter = document.getElementById('diameter').value;
   var species = document.getElementById('species').value;

   // calculate the age of the tree based on the diameter and species
   var age = (diameter / species) * 60;

   // display the result in the "result" paragraph
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'The age of the tree is ' + age + ' years';
}
```

I have added this code to WordPress website by creating a new JavaScript file and enqueuing it in the theme's functions.php file.

```
function enqueue_tree_age_calculator_script() {
   wp_enqueue_script('tree-age-calculator', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tree-age-calculator.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_tree_age_calculator_script');
```

But it seems WP Post can't parse the script, nor even "php echo" on body. Here's the post that I tried: https://sarpo.net/tree-age-calculator/

Comment: The calculator seems working on your given link.